# Linq Union ordering - how do i ensure items from the first IEnumerable remain first in result?

Tags: c#, linq

i'd like to figure out if it's possible (or, if it's already being done) to ensure the items from the first IEnumerable are kept - while duplicates from a union of another IEnumerable are discarded.

For example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyApp.ExampleStuff
{
public class SomeDto
{
    string name {get; set;}
    int classId {get; set;}
    int notComparedObject {get; set;}
}

public class test {

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        IEnumerable<SomeDto> firstDto = new List<SomeDto>() { new SomeDto() {name = "Dave", classId = 1, notComparedObject = 12}};
        IEnumerable<SomeDto> secondDto = new List<SomeDto>() { new SomeDto() {name = "Dave", classId = 1, notComparedObject = 16}, new SomeDto() {name = "Brad", classId = 1, notComparedObject = 77}};

        var result = GetUnionedLists(firstDto, secondDto);
    }

    public ILookup<SomeDto> GetUnionedLists (IEnumerable<SomeDto> dtoA, IEnumerable<SomeDto> dtoB)
    {
            return dtoA.Union(dtoB, new SomeDtoComparer()).ToLookUp(x => x.classId);
    }

}

public class SomeDtoComparer : IEqualityComparer<SomeDto>
    {
        public bool Equals(SomeDto SomeDtoA, SomeDto SomeDtoB)
        {
            if (SomeDtoA == null && SomeDtoB == null)
            {
                return true;
            } else if (SomeDtoA == null || SomeDtoB == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return (SomeDtoA.Name == SomeDtoB.Name && SomeDtoA.classId == SomeDtoB.classId);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(SomeDto SomeDtoX)
        {
            int hashName = SomeDtoX.Name == null ? 0 : SomeDtoX.Name.GetHashCode();
            int hashClassId  = SomeDtoX.classId == null ? 0 : SomeDtoX.classId.GetHashCode();

            return hashName ^ hashClassId;
        }
    }
}
```

If this is run - i would hope that the value of result in DoSomething() is a Lookup containing only the following someDto's under classId "1":

```
SomeDto() {name = "Dave", classId = 1, notComparedObject = 12}
SomeDto() {name = "Brad", classId = 1, notComparedObject = 77}
```

As you can see, if "Name" and "classId" are the same - the results are considered Equal, and i'd then like to keep the item from the original IEnumerable, and discard the "duplicate" - in this case that was:

```
SomeDto() {name = "Dave", id = 1, notComparedObject = 16}
```

If the result were to come out like this - it would be considered wrong (as the items from the second Enumerable were placed first in the result):

```
SomeDto() {name = "Brad", classId = 1, notComparedObject = 77}
SomeDto() {name = "Dave", classId = 1, notComparedObject = 12}
```

Comment: Is this Linq-To-Objects or Linq-To-Entities (or any other DB-driven LINQ provider)? If it's translated to a sql query you cannot guarantee the order without an explicit `OrderBy`. With LInq-To-Objects `Union` does it already: _"When the object returned by this method is enumerated, `Union<TSource>` **enumerates first and second in that order and yields each element that has not already been yielded**."_

Comment: System.Linq - using the Enumerables Class.

Comment: Reading https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407(v=vs.110).aspx i now see what you mean @TimSchmelter So it's already working the way i wanted it to. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Enumerable.Union` method already yields items in order that you've described. It's written in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358407(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) that

> When the object returned by this method is enumerated, Union **enumerates first and second in that order** and yields each element that has not already been yielded.

On the other side, `Lookup` type as well as `IGrouping` interface does not give any guarantees on elements order (looks like current implementation of [`ToLookup`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,86a042202a06bb2c) keeps the original order, but this could change). So if it really matters, you should add some additional logic — like using custom type instead of `Lookup`, adding custom property for index and ordering by it or, probably, using `GroupBy`, which does guarantees the order as it's stated in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2).

> The IGrouping objects are yielded in an order based on the order of the elements in source that produced the first key of each IGrouping. Elements in a grouping are **yielded in the order that the elements that produced them appear in source**.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do this using the FullJoin function available within the MoreLinq library (available on NuGet).

https://morelinq.github.io/3.0/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_FullJoin__3_1.htm

Example:

```
public ILookup<SomeDto> GetUnionedLists (IEnumerable<SomeDto> dtoA, IEnumerable<SomeDto> dtoB)
{
        return dtoA
            .FullJoin(dtoB, 
                 e => e, 
                 first => first,
                 second => second, 
                 (first, second) => first, 
                 new SomeDtoComparer())
            .ToLookUp(x => x.classId);
}
```